# Parsing embedded Json Dictionaries in Swift 3

Tags: json, swift3

The conversion to swift 3 has caused some errors in the code i use to parse Json. I have searched up others who had similar problems but none of them were instances were there were dictionaries within dictionaries and so forth. I understand the need to now cast the "any" portion when pulling information from dictionaries but I am not sure how to proceed with embedded ones. My code is below

```
func parseJson(_ JsonDict: NSDictionary)
{
    var data = [newsarticle]()
    var placeholder: NSDictionary
    var names = JsonDict["result"]!["ReturnValue"]!!["tree"] as! [NSArray]
    let childDict = names[0] as! NSDictionary
    names = childDict["children"] as! NSArray
    for element in names{
        placeholder = element as! NSDictionary
        data.append(newsarticle(name: placeholder["text"] as! String,desc: "https://www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/\(placeholder["id"] as! NSNumber)/689493"))
    }
    addData(data)

}
```

The Json Dict I am parsing:

```
{  
   "type":"rpc",
   "tid":2,
   "action":"Websites",
   "method":"school_webpage",
   "result":{  
      "CurrentStatus":1,
      "Description":"OK",
      "ReturnValue":{  
         "splash":"",
         "bgcolor":"#FFFFFF",
         "tree":[  
            {  
               "text":"Staff Websites",
               "expanded":true,
               "children":[  
                  {  
                     "id":462793,
                     "text":"Ahrens, Linda",
                     "iconCls":"icn-add",
                     "leaf":true,
                     "type":"website",
                     "showAdd":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":498858,
                     "text":"Altemose, David",
                     "iconCls":"icn-add",
                     "leaf":true,
                     "type":"website",
                     "showAdd":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":11159347,
                     "text":"Alvin, Patrick",
                     "iconCls":"icn-add",
                     "leaf":true,
                     "type":"website",
                     "showAdd":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":492376,
                     "text":"Anderson, Kelly",
                     "iconCls":"icn-add",
                     "leaf":true,
                     "type":"website",
                     "showAdd":false
                  },
                  {  
                     "id":11247466,
                     "text":"Anderson, Michael",
                     "iconCls":"icn-add",
                     "leaf":true,
                     "type":"website",
                     "showAdd":false
                  }

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correctly modified version based off of Amit's code

```
func parseJson(_ JsonDict: AnyObject)
        {
            var data = [newsarticle]()
            let dict = JsonDict as? [String: AnyObject]
                if let dict2 = dict?["result"]?["ReturnValue"]{
                    if let dict3 = (dict2 as! [String: AnyObject])["tree"]  as? [AnyObject] {
                        for dict4  in dict3 {
                            if let dict5 = dict4["children"]  as? [AnyObject]{
                                for dict6 in dict5{
                                    let datum = dict6 as? [String: AnyObject]
                                    data.append(newsarticle(name: (datum?["text"])! as! String,desc: "https://www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/\(datum?["id"] as! NSNumber)/689493"))
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        addData(data)
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 func parseJson(_ JsonDict: AnyObject)
    {
        var data = [newsarticle]()

        if let nameDic = JsonDict!["result"]["ReturnValue"]["tree"]["children"]  as? [AnyObject] {

            for dict2  in nameDic {
                 data.append(newsarticle(name: (dict2 as? [String : AnyObject])?["text"],desc: "https://www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/\((dict2 as? [String : AnyObject])?["id"])/689493"))

            }
        }

          addData(data)

    }
```

Comment: I cannot cast JsonDict (!) because it is non optional. taking out the ! leaves me with the same error

Comment: @praveen give me the proper dict that you want to retrieve value from

Comment: I have added the Dict. This Dict is a shortened version but contains all the correct nodes.

Comment: in my case ,this parsing is correctly working in swift 3

Comment: Amit, I have attached Images of the errors I am getting. http://imgur.com/a/16vEk?

Comment: @praveen i have attached new answer ,may be it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var data = [newsarticle]()
do{
if  let jsonData = (JsonDict as AnyObject).data(using:   String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            {
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData,       options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers )

    if let dict = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject]
    {
        if let dict2 = (dict as? [String : AnyObject])?["result"]?["ReturnValue"]{

            if let dic3 = dict2!["tree"]  as? [AnyObject] {

                for dict4  in dict3 {
                    if let dic5 = dict4!["children"]  as? [AnyObject]{
                        for dic6 in dec5{
                            data.append(newsarticle(name: (dic6 as? [String : AnyObject])?["text"],desc: "https://www.oncoursesystems.com/school/webpage/\((dic6 as? [String : AnyObject])?["id"])/689493"))
                        }

                    }
                }
                 addData(data)
            }
        }


        }


    }

}catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")

}
```

}

Comment: Amit, this solves the original problem but this code will not compile due to the following error:  Cannot invoke 'jsonObject' with an argument list of type '(with: AnyObject, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions)'

Comment: user "JsonDict" as let jsonData = (value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

Comment: sorry,just ignore it,
user "JsonDict" as follow:-

Comment: Amit your code was close, but I had to make small changes in order for it work. I have attached the working code above as the answer